# factoring catch clause in try catch

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, try-catch

I my program have multiple `do-try-catch` clause but I'm using the same `catch` function all through out, how can I factor it out?

E.g

```
func tryCatch1 {
   do{
     try something.save
   }catch let error as UserError{
     print(error.description)
   }
}


// Another try catch

func tryCatch2 {

       do{
         try somethingAgain.save
       }catch let error as UserError{
         print(error.description)
       }
 }
```

Is it possible to create something like **"universal catch"**

Comment: Why catch in the low level functions?  Simply throw the exception. It is typically best to catch the exception at the highest level

Comment: @Paulw11 can you explain further?

Comment: Use try/catch that way is rather pointless, isn't it? If you don't do something useful, you might as well use try! and at least the user notices that something is wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729 that is just an example to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find yourself typing the same boilerplate code again and again, you may want to create an Xcode "Code Snippet" that you call with a simple sequence of characters.

In Xcode, open the right-side "Utilities" panel (you can use the last of the three little square icons at the upper-right for that).

In the lower part there's the section where you usually pick the UI objects: click on the `{ }` icon, named "Show the code snippet library". you can now see a list of premade snippets.

To make yours, select your code in Xcode with the mouse, complete with the indentation:

```
do {

} catch let error as UserError {
    print(error.description)
}
```

Then *drag* the selected code to the snippets section *(you can hold the ALT (option) key when dragging for a visual help)*.

The snippets section highlight: drop the selection, it creates a new snippet at the bottom.

Click on it, click on edit: make your own title, description, shortcut, etc.

Now everytime in your code, at the chosen scope, when you type the shortcut, it is replaced by the snippet.

If my snippet has a shortcut of "dtc" (just an example, choose something that will not interfere will your code or Swift keywords), I just have to type "dtc" and "dtc" is replaced by the whole Do-Try-Catch block from the snippets.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, This is a very handy trick! but why should "Alt" be hold, mine works even if I'm not holding alt, just click and drag.

Comment: You're welcome. You're right that ALT is not mandatory, I just like to enforce it because it changes the mouse cursor from the selector to a cross - I find it helping for dragging the text.